# Where is `scanf` implementation source code?

Tags: c, source, printf

I want to find C source code for `scanf` implementation on Linux machine. Googling to find `scanf` implementation does not tell me the way to find it. I tried to find that source code from `gcc` source tree using `ctags` and `cscope`, but I could not find it. Can anybody please tell me where is `scanf` function definition, i.e. implementation source code?

Comment: You can often obtain this information directly via your distribution. It's easy with Debian/Ubuntu, for example. What is your distribution?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in `glibc` library [scanf.c source](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.33/scanf_8c_source.html)

`glibc` stands for **GNU C Library**. It is a C standard library implementation. It's not a part of the compiler, because you might have different implementations of it (like Microsoft C run-time for example) as well as different compilers (like `clang`).

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! could you please elaborate why that source code is not included(?) in my gcc source tree? I don't know what `glibc` does(support) for my hello_world program.

Comment: It's the primary library of functions and definitions for C programs. It contains the function you are looking for `scanf()`

Comment: Just worth pointing out that other C standard libraries and therefore `scanf` implementations exist as well, e.g. uClibc: https://github.com/ffainelli/uClibc/blob/master/libc/stdio/_scanf.c